# How to determine current distance between two planets

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

I'd like to add a feature to one of my apps that calculates the current distance between the Earth and Mars (or any other planet, for that matter). My google searches have led me to statistics of average distances (as a planets orbit is elliptical, and therefore the distance can vary greatly), as well as articles about Keplers laws of Planetary motion and more.

Unfortunately, I haven't found any readings explicitly describing how to calculate the current distance between two planets. So, how is this done?

I apologize in advance if the tags on this question are incorrect.

Please explain your answer and the steps needed, so that I may understand better.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain how your app works? I mean: how do you compute the current distance between the Earth and Mars?

Comment: That is what this question is asking.

Comment: Ah, OK: I thought you already had that part working. There should be out there some free code to compute planets positions, I think: doing that from scratch is too complicated, in my opinion. Once you know the positions in some coordinate system, finding the distances is easy.

Comment: See this for instance: http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=464